# Get tree in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data

I have a data many to many relationship. 
E.g one main parent can have multiple children and those children can have multiple parents.

My main table is

```
| id | name            | depth  |
---------------------------------
 1   |  top parent     |    0
 2   |  child1 of 1    |    1
 3   |  child2 of 1    |    1
 4   |  child1 of 2    |    2
 5   |  child2 of 2/3  |    2
 6   |  child1 of 5    |    3
```

And linked table looks like

```
| childId | parentId |
----------------------
    2     |    1
    3     |    1 
    4     |    2
    5     |    2
    5     |    3 
    6     |    5
```

Now I want to get all direct parents, siblings and direct children of given entry. For example  for id 5 I want to get 2,3, 4 and 6. I am new at PostgreSql. How can I do it in one query? I need to order the result by name and paginate.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need recursive queries for that.

Get the direct parents:

```
SELECT parent_id
FROM link
WHERE child_id = 5;
┌───────────┐
│ parent_id │
├───────────┤
│         2 │
│         3 │
└───────────┘
(2 rows)
```

Get the siblings:

```
SELECT b.child_id AS sibling_id
FROM link a
   JOIN link b USING (parent_id)
WHERE a.child_id = 5
   AND b.child_id <> 5;
┌────────────┐
│ sibling_id │
├────────────┤
│          4 │
└────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Get the children:

```
SELECT child_id
FROM link
WHERE parent_id = 5;
┌──────────┐
│ child_id │
├──────────┤
│        6 │
└──────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had this idea, but I thought I could do it in one query . Also I need to order whole result and it can be hundreds of records.

Comment: Sure, you can do that. There is `ORDER BY`. If you want to do it in one query, you'd have to specify how you want the result to look, since there are different numbers of result rows for each query. Maybe [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you every combination (parents/siblings/children).

```
select m.id, m.name,string_agg(distinct t.ids::text,',')
from main_table m
join linked_table l on l.childid = m.id or l.parentid = m.id 
join linked_table l3 USING(parentid),
unnest(ARRAY[l.parentid,l.childid,l3.childid]) as t(ids)
where t.ids <> m.id
group by m.id, m.name
order by m.name;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Group By does not work it is showing multiple rows for same names

Comment: i have added  `string_agg()` to the query.